# npm install from bare git file repo

Tags: git, npm, git-bare

how can I install an npm module from a bare git repo folder?

So I have a folder that contains a git repo. It was created with `git init --bare`.
Now I want npm to fetch the latest version of the master branch, and there a package.json file is avaliable.

What is the right way to do this?

I tried stuff like:

```
npm install git+file:///W:/my/git/repo/ -g
npm install git+file:///W:/my/git/repo/#master -g
npm install file:///W:/my/git/repo/ -g --from-git
```

Is it even possible?

The npm log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'file:///W:/my/git/repo/',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '--from-git' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.14
3 info using node@v0.10.29
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'file:///W:/my/git/repo/', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="file:///W:/my/git/repo/" args=["file:///W:/my/git/repo/",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: 'file:',
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: true,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: '',
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: '',
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: '/W:/my/git/repo/',
7 verbose parsed url   path: '/W:/my/git/repo/',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'file:///W:/my/git/repo/' }
8 silly lockFile cc42952a--W-my-git-repo file:///W:/my/git/repo/
9 verbose lock file:///W:/my/git/repo/ C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cc42952a--W-my-git-repo.lock
10 silly lockFile cc42952a--W-my-git-repo file:///W:/my/git/repo/
11 silly lockFile cc42952a--W-my-git-repo file:///W:/my/git/repo/
12 error addLocal Could not install file:///W:/my/git/repo/
13 error Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\test\file:\W:\my\git\repo'
14 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
14 error including the npm and node versions, at:
14 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
15 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
16 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "file:///W:/my/git/repo/" "-g" "--from-git"
17 error cwd C:\test
18 error node -v v0.10.29
19 error npm -v 1.4.14
20 error path C:\test\file:\W:\my\git\repo
21 error code ENOENT
22 error errno 34
23 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Comment: The path `20 error path C:\test\file:\W:\my\git\repo` seems incorrect

Comment: well, `C:\test\` is the current working directory. I still dont understand why I get this error.

Comment: For what it's worth, as of this writing, I'm able to use `npm install git+file:///C:/my/favorite/bare/repository/` just fine.  On a related note, dont forget about `npm link`, which makes development a bit easier.

Answer (score 6):

I have a hacky answer, which might be better than no answer at all. Use Git's URL rewriting feature:

```
git config --global url.file://.insteadOf git+file://
npm install git+file:///c:\dev\code\mymod
```

It generates warnings about not being able to fetch remotes, etc., but it installs the module and `npm` exits with a success code.

This works because the `git+` prefix makes NPM pass the whole path to Git, and then the URL rewrite rule turns `git+file://` (an invalid Git protocol string) into `file://` (a valid Git protocol string).

Comment: Interesting! I will try this the next time I need it.

Comment: Works for me on macOS with a network volume, thank you!

Answer (score -4):

per https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

**Git URLs as Dependencies**

Git urls can be of the form:

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

The commit-ish can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to git checkout. The default is master.

The documentation is specifically for the `package.json` file, but you can also do things like:
`npm install git://github.com/user/project.git#develop_branch`.

Comment: This is absolutely not an answer. It does not answer how to use a git bare repo folder.